# MAC and IP address text-identicon as avatar

Tags: mac-address, uniqueidentifier

I would like to create something like identicons but not with images but with a unique word for each IP-Addresses and MAC-Addresses.

create an easy to remember alias for a mac address, that is unique and reverse lookupable, for example:

IP 123.456.789.132 will result in an alias for that IP, that is connected to an existing word from a wordlist, that is unique.

Background of this idea:
this way we could identify our Routers in our Opennet in Hamburg easily in a graphical NodeGraph.

There are a lot of sites, that generate graphical avatars:
gravatar (Identicon, MonsterID, Wavatar), Retro, vanillicon, VisiGlyphs or unicornify

Is there some site already, where I can convert MAC-Adresses to unique human readeable synonyms?

Comment: a MAC address is a 48 bit **number**. Use some simple math to make the number smaller (e.g. only the last X bits) and match that to a list of words.

Answer (score 1):

As Hennes notes above, a MAC address is a 48-bit number; an IPv4 address is a 32-bit number.  Let's not think about IPv6 yet.

Amazon.com says that the stock paperback Merriam-Webster dictionary contains "over 60,000 words", which is about 16 bits of space.  That means that you can do this mapping yourself, by getting a list of 65,536 English (or your preferred language) words, and mapping them on a one-to-one basis with pairs of octets.

A 16-bit list means that an IP address will need two such words, and a MAC address three.

If the full English (or other) dictionary includes words that are too difficult to remember ("my MAC address is `capybara nephtyids oleaginous`") then you could get a list of the 16,384 most common words, and map into that 12-bit space; that means 3 per IPv4 address, and four per MAC address.

All you need to do is choose your word list, and start counting down it.  Wiktionary might be a good place to get a reasonably-usable list with tolerable conditions on its use.

Comment: http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/